# Let ${\{x^k\}}^{\infty}_{k=1}$ $\subset R^n$ be a convergent sequence, prove that there exists $B > 0$ such that $∥x^k∥ ≤ B$ for all $k$.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, optimization

Let ${\{x^k\}}^{\infty}_{k=1}$ $\subset  R^n$ be a convergent sequence,
prove that there exists $B > 0$ such that $∥x^k∥ ≤ B$ for all $k$.

I am struggling to prove this and would really appreciate help with proving it, thank you!

Comment: Any thoughts you have? Why do you intuitively think it is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the definition of convergence: since $\{x^k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ converges there is some $x$ that it converges to, and $\|x^k-x\|\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$.  So there exists some $N\in {\mathbb N}$ such that $\| x^k - x\| < \epsilon$ whenever $k > N$ (clearly $\epsilon >0$ but otherwise we can choose $\epsilon$ to be anything we like).

Rearrange a little, and we get $\|x\|-\epsilon < \|x^k\| < \|x\| + \epsilon$

At this point, I think you can probably fill in the missing details for yourself :)

Comment: Eh, you just need $||x^k|| < ||x||+\epsilon$ since $||x^k|| \ge 0$ but not a big deal.

Comment: @mathworker21 True, but there will be other proofs later on where it's useful to have both sides of the inequality -- may as well be introduced to it now :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have some questions, which I hope you wouldn't mind clarifying? 1. Here you used $\epsilon$ instead of $B$ correct? 2. I am unable to follow how you obtained the equation after re-arranging? Thank you! @postmortes

Comment: Actually I've used $\|x\|$ instead of $B$.  You might have a definition of convergence that looks like $\|x^k - B\| \rightarrow 0$, so set $x$ to be $B$ and you'll see it.

For the rearranged equation: if $x^k$ is closer then $\epsilon$ to $x$ then it must be greater than $x-\epsilon$ and less than $x+\epsilon$, otherwise it would be further away than we're allowed.  That's what the rearranged equation expresses (try putting some positive and negative numbers in for $x$ to get a feel for what it means)

Comment: I worked through it and it makes much more sense now, thank you!